# How to create custom fields in JIRA, and fetch the fields' data to external program?

Tags: api, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I want to create a custom text field in user stories of JIRA. Once the custom field is created, when someone inserts/updates the custom field, I want to fetch the data on custom field to an external program in any format (i.e. String, JSON, .doc, .xls, .csv etc.)

P.S. I'm not a JIRA Administrator.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/adding-a-custom-field-802592519.html) documentation from JIRA provides you simple steps on how to add a custom field on JIRA for your own project, but for this to happen - you have to be a JIRA Administrator. This can't be helped much, as this is a limitation from JIRA itself.

But having said that, if you get it sorted from a JIRA Administrator from your Organization - getting the details of the newly added custom field is not that difficult. JIRA REST APIs will come to rescue in that scenario.

You can simply fire the following `REST` `GET` `API` call to get the details that are intended to known by you!

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.fred.com/rest/api/2/issue/FRD-88651
```

The call will further provide you the necessary details! Hope this answers your query!

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it once I contact the JIRA administrator.

Comment: Hi @N00b pr0grammer, do you have any idea how to fetch default values of user stories in JIRA ?